# Fastest way with parallelization to compute distances between two points with Python code

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing

I have a data frame 'data' with millions of rows. Each row has coordinates ('x','y'), I would like to compute distances among consecutive pairs of the coordinates in the most efficient way python can provide. Will parallelization help here?

I saw approaches here that suggests to use cython. However I would like to see only python solutions.

Here is the snippet of my data

```
points = 
[(26406, -6869),
 (27679, -221),
 (27679, -221),
 (26416, -6156),
 (26679, -578),
 (26679, -580),
 (27813, -558),
 (26254, -1097),
 (26679, -580),
 (27813, -558),
 (28258, -893),
 (26253, -1098),
 (26678, -581),
 (27811, -558),
 (28259, -893),
 (26252, -1098),
 (27230, -481),
 (26679, -582),
 (27488, -5849),
 (27811, -558),
 (28259, -893),
 (26250, -1099),
 (27228, -481),
 (26679, -582),
 (27488, -5847),
 (28525, -1465),
 (27811, -558),
 (28259, -892)]
```

I believe that my first approach using for-loop can be definitely improved:

```
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    def comp_dist(points):
        size  =len(points)
        d = 0
        i=1
        for i in range(1,size):
            if i%1000000==0:
                print i
            # print "i-1:", points[i-1]
            # print "i: ", points[i]
            dist = distance.euclidean(points[i-1],points[i])
            d= d+dist
        print d

    distance = comp_dist(points)
```

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Using numpy would be faster than your current solution, and a lot easier to implement than Cython. It won't give you parallelization, though (but it might be optimized for your CPU, for example).

Comment: If your going to go down the multiprocessing route, you need to split your big list into chunks, process these and then merge them at the end

Comment: Do you think it will improve performance?

Comment: It depends on the size of your data, there is a cost of starting jobs in parallel, but this is offset as the size of the data increases. If your task completes in milli seconds it is generally not worth it

Comment: I have 49 millions of coordinates

Comment: Then it should be quicker

Comment: are you able to load the whole list into memory or do you read it by chunks?

Comment: Yes, I am able to load it in memory.

Answer (score 3):

You said python, but since you're already using scipy for the distance calculation I assume that a numpy solution is ok.

Using a vectorized, single-threaded operation on a 28 million point numpy array takes only 1 second on my laptop.  Using a 32-bit integer data type, the array occupies about 200MB in memory.

```py
import numpy as np
points = [(26406, -6869), ..., (28259, -892)]
# make test array my repeating the 28-element points list 1M times
np_points = np.array(points*1000000, dtype='int32')
# use two different slices (offset by 1) from resulting array;
# execution of next line takes ~1 second
dists = np.sqrt(np.sum((np_points[0:-2] - np_points[1:-1])**2, axis=1))
```

```py
print(dists.shape)
(27999998,)

print(dists[:28])
[  6.76878372e+03   0.00000000e+00   6.06789865e+03   5.58419672e+03
   2.00000000e+00   1.13421338e+03   1.64954600e+03   6.69263775e+02
   1.13421338e+03   5.57000898e+02   2.01545280e+03   6.69263775e+02
   1.13323343e+03   5.59400572e+02   2.01744244e+03   1.15636197e+03
   5.60180328e+02   5.32876815e+03   5.30084993e+03   5.59400572e+02
   2.01953386e+03   1.15689585e+03   5.58213221e+02   5.32679134e+03
   4.50303153e+03   1.15431581e+03   5.58802291e+02   6.25764636e+03]
```

Comment: You could combine this with process-level parallelization, but it's unlikely to help since the overhead of copying along with process initialization is large relative to the amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example to help you get started:

```python
from scipy.spatial import distance
from multiprocessing import Pool

processes = 4

# Group data into pairs in order to compute distance
pairs = [(points[i], points[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1)]
print pairs

# Split data into chunks
l = [pairs[i:i+processes] for i in xrange(0, len(pairs), processes)]


def worker(lst):
    return [distance.euclidean(i[0], i[1]) for i in lst]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes)
    result = p.map(worker, l)
    # Flatten list
    print [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]
```

Testing this with:

```
points =[(random.randint(0,1000), random.randint(0, 1000)) for i in range(1000000)]
```

With 8 processes it takes around 5 seconds, with 1 takes over 10 seconds.